# How to handle css modules with ?module suffix in Jest

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, jestjs, webpack-encore

I'm building a react app that mixes global css with css modules using Symfony's webpack encore. To avoid global CSS issues I've settled on using `import 'app.css'` for global styles and `import styles from 'component.css?module'` in my components. This is working as expected, however Jest is not pruning the ?module from the css module import and cannot find the file, giving me errors like `Cannot find module './login.module.css?module' from 'assets/pages/Login/index.jsx'`.

Does anyone know how to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issue and fixed it with something like that (with Webpack Encore) :

```
.configureCssLoader(options => {
options.modules = {
  auto: /\.module\.\w+$/i
}})
```

And now you can create a file with '.module.scss' suffix, and you can import it in a ts file. (working with jest, unlike ?module)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself. If anyone is interested, I enabled css modules in `webpack.config.js` by adding

```
.configureCssLoader((options) => {
  options.modules = true;
})
```

However this then applies css module loading to all .css files and breaks global css rules.

So I modified the webpack config manually using the following at the end of `webpack.config.js`

```
const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

// only include files ending in module.css in the module css loader
config.module.rules[1].include = /\.module\.css$/;
// add another css loader without modules enabled to parse global css files
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
  exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
});

module.exports = config;
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but seems to be working ok at the moment!